# Can't load Java Library

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and I am trying to run a program I got from a friend. I keep getting this error and I'm unsure how to solve the problem.

Application is starting. Fetching data. Please wait... (approx. 10s)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-cocoa-4236 in java.library.path
        no swt-cocoa in java.library.path
        Can't load library: C:\Users\Andrew.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-cocoa-4236.dll
        Can't load library: C:\Users\Andrew.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-cocoa.dll

```
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.interal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:101)
    at view.MainWindow.open(MainWindow.java:77)
    at view.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:65)
```

Apparently I'm missing the SWT library (swt-cocoa-4236 and/or swt-cocoa?), but I have no idea where to get it. That statement probably reveals my ignorance. If anyone could even point me in the right direction to where I might be able to solve the problem I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the program that you are running is not built for your OS. SWT is OS dependant and JVM depedant. All SWT programs will use `swt.jar` which will be different based on the underlying OS. The one the program is using is built for Mac OS and seems like you are running that on a non-Mac system.

Regarding 'How to solve it', it depends on how the program that you are running is packaged.

Check the java version you are using and download appropriate SWT jar file.

Comment: Judging by the pathnames, the OP is running on Windows.

Comment: True, Windows, but again the JVM version will come into picture for Windows SWT

Comment: I completely forgot to mention I'm running Windows 7 but it seems I didn't need to. You must be a pro. 

Can you elaborate on what you mean by how the program is packaged?

Comment: How are you running the program? What is the folder structure of where the program is? Most probably there should be a `lib` folder where you can find the jar files. Look for `swt` jar file there.

Comment: I just put the program on my desktop after downloading it from Google drive. I've been running it from the command window using "java -jar". I don't see lib folder in the program folder.

Comment: Is that a single `.jar` file?

Comment: If it is a single `.jar` file, then extract the contents of that file using a unzip utility. Check for the `swt` jar file. Most probably it should it something like `swt-X.Y.Z-cocoa-....jar`. Check your java version using `java -version` and then download the appropriate `swt` version from [link](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and rename that to be the same as what you already have and replace it in the extracted folder. Zip the files again into a jar. That should suffice.

Comment: Yes, it's just one jar file and it has a conf folder and a resources folder.

Comment: To unzip it could I use winrar or would I need something specific to java?

Comment: You can use any unzipping utility, as the classpath is already built earlier

Comment: Ok I found where the file is supposed to be, but there is nothing there at all. There was a folder C:\Users\Andrew\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64 that was completely empty. When I tried again after downloading the file from the link and extracting it to that location, I still got the same error.

Comment: you didn't find the swt jar file in the files extracted from your jar?

Comment: There is no swt.jar file in the files extracted from the program. There is a folder titled swt which contains many other folders which all contain .class files. However, my last comment was referring to the file pathway in the original error message. I looked in the specified folder and it was empty.

Comment: May be you can try this:
1) Download the SWT jar file appropriate to your environment as indicated earlier.
2) Keep the SWT jar in the same folder where your jar is.
3) Run the program using this command:
    java -jar -cp <SWT-Jar-name.jar> <YOUR_JAR_NAME.jar>

Comment: I just tried and it simply said "< was unexpected at this time."

Answer (score 2):

I think Mubin (i.e. the above answer) is correct. here is where you can download the specific  version of SWT.jar for your environment http://www.eclipse.org/swt/.

(I am answering your question for "I have no idea where to get it.")

Comment: Thank you this really helps. Are there any special installation instructions?

Comment: @DrewMerritt welcome, please feel free to give it 1+ for the answer for the usefulness. Happy I could help. There is a tutorial on the page http://www.eclipse.org/swt/docs.php.

Answer (score 0):

little late to the game, but i just had the same problem and found [this solution](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=368757&goto=908129&#msg_908129):

> Here's what worked for me:
>
> Right Click on your Project Folder of your HelloWorldSWT Project-> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Tab 'Projects'
>
> Expand the 'org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64' folder by clicking on the arrow left to it
>
> Select 'Native library location' and click Edit
>
> Click the Workspace Button and select 'org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64', then click ok (serveral times).
>
> That did the trick ... Ma-an